# Mark more than one word in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I have a filter to mark a word from a list. I would like the word to be marked at the same time according to the title or the name. The filter is currently only done by the title, I would like the filter to be made by the name too.
How can I do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/e4njevts/1/

```
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.data = [
              { title: "Bad",name:'bill' },
              { title: "Good",name:'Goe' },
              { title: "Great",name:'Brad' },
              { title: "Cool",name:'yan' },
              { title: "Excellent",name:'mikle' },
              { title: "Awesome",name:'mosa' },
              { title: "Horrible",name:'morteza' },
            ]

  }).filter('highlight', function($sce) {
      return function(text, phrase) {
        if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
          '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text)
      }
    })
```

I need that..

[image]

Comment: Like [this?](https://jsfiddle.net/umb55xaq/) You might have to edit the model names and the filter though

Comment: @George great! can you help me with a problem with this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266722/my-directive-stops-working-when-using-another-angular-js

Comment: please, I need mark your answer as solution