# My directive stops working combined with another.. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a directive to edit a field dynamically called "click-to-edit". If I click on an item, I can edit it without problems.

```
<span ng-click="ignoreClick($event);" >
  <a href='' click-to-edit item="faq" ng-model='faq.pregunta'
     typeinput='textarea'>{{faq.pregunta}}
  </a>
```

I have a filter that highlights a word when it is found, this filter is called 
"highligth". If I add the line

```
ng-bind-html="faq.pregunta | highlight:search.pregunta"
```

I can not click to edit the field.

but the filter works for me to highlight. I need to not miss the functionality of editing the fields without it being damaged when the text is highlighted. How can I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/jv5o6s8y/

Comment: no offence but that is somewhat a poorly asked question. The "template" inside your directive is quite messy and you have a lot of comments which I find irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @ZombieChowder Okay, I'll correct it.

Comment: @ZombieChowder https://jsfiddle.net/jv5o6s8y/

Comment: nvm. I'm just writing your answer

Comment: no idea sry. I just know that everything works when you remove the `.filter`.

Comment: @ZombieChowder yes...

Comment: @yavg can you try using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` instead of `ng-bind-html` please?

Comment: @quirimmo I already tried it but it does not work, here is the link if you need it.
https://jsfiddle.net/jv5o6s8y/

Comment: sorry just read your answer. Let me do some test. It should work using `unsafe`

Comment: @quirimmo Thanks, I tried what you say, but it does not work. When highlighting the text, my directive stops editing fields.

Comment: @yavg could you explain me how to highlight a word please? I am sorry but maybe it's because of the Spanish, I can't understand how to reproduce the highlighting :D p.s. found it, never mind :D

Comment: @quirimmo hablas español? do you speak spanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with `ng-bind-html` is that it replaces the directive's template, that is why you are not able to click inside the directive (original `ng-click` with toggle will not work), it doesn't contain the initial template. 
You should highlight the text somewhere inside your directives template, like:

```
<div class="hover-text-field" ng-show="!editState" ng-click="toggle()" ng-bind-html="model | highlight:search.pregunta"></div>
```

, check this working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bgk4pc5z/).

Comment: Have you checked my jsfiddle? What is not working for you? I can edit the content inside the opened section.

Comment: To allow the header to be edited we should also make the same change to it - just replace `ng-bind-html` with `search="search"` binding - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bgk4pc5z/1/).